# Validating GMT date with gmtoffset

Tags: java

I have an

i) integer variable called gmtoffset (which is the number of hours/minutes to add/subtract from the base time) and

ii) map object(called result) which contains the timestamp in GMT . I need to iterate into map object and change the timestamp inside the map object by adding/subtracting according to the no of hours in gmtoffset variable.

For e.g, `int gmtoffset = 0230 , changedTimestamp = 2013-09-11 01:11:00.1`

My final changedTimestamp variable should be `2013-09-11 10:41:00.1`

Request help.

Comment: what have you tried?  Why a map and not a list?  Does your offset contain minutes or hours?  are you adding or subtracting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Java Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to do the job. Something like the following:

```
Date date = <convert your changedTimesetamp to a date, see SimpleDateFormat>
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, gmtoffset);
```

Note: Assuming gmtoffset is express in minutes... so 2 hours and 30 minutes would be 150 minutes.